# AdMobPro on iOS shows an empty white banner (Cordova App)

Tags: cordova, admob

It works like a charm on Android, but on iOS plugin shows only white empty banner and app itself crashes a few seconds after start.

Any suggestions?

P.S. I've already created two separate admob keys for Android and iOS, so there is no issue here =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved by aligning application events: `deviceready`and `online`.

Somehow, an online event was called before `deviceready`where I should wait for Cordova to load (and where I initialized ad mob itself). So, no ad mob initialization placed in `deviceready`event handler was never called.

Voilla =)